# The question is related to stochastic process and the Markov chains

Tags: self-study, stochastic-processes, markov-process

This is the complete question.

Jim is currently living in Scranton. Each year that he lives in Scranton, he has a
probability of 1/2 of staying in Scranton the next year. Otherwise, he has an equally
likely chance of moving to Chicago, Philadelphia, New York, or Seattle, the next year.
On any given year that he lives in Philadelphia, he has a 1/4 probability of moving to
Seattle, a probability of 3/8 of moving to Scranton and a probability of 3/8 of moving to
Chicago the next year. On any year that he lives in Chicago, he has a probability of 1/2
of moving to New York, a probability of 3/8 of moving to Scranton and a probability of
1/8 of moving to Philadelphia the next year.
In answering the questions below, assume Jim will be living in one of the 5 cities forever.
Also assume, for parts (a)-(e) that if Jim moves to Seattle or New York, he will stay
there and will not relocate again.

1. Is this a valid Markov chain? Create the transition graph and matrix.
2. What is the probability that Jim eventually will leave the non-Coastal cities (i.e.,
   Scranton, Chicago, Philadelphia) permanently?
3. What is the probability that Jim will eventually relocate permanently to New
   York?
4. What is the expected number of years until Jim leaves Scranton permanently?
5. Jim’s friend Karen also started out like Jim but in Chicago. She also eventually
   relocated to New York or Seattle. What is the expected number of years she lived
   in Scranton?

for the first five parts i could only be able to obtained the probability transition matrix and i will inculed it here.

[image: Transition matrix]

- Also for the part 2 it is asking eventual probabilities which means i have to calculate the limiting probabilities. Is that right?
- for the part 4 and 5 do we need to consider the matrix as transient?
- if anyone can help with these questions i will be very thank full.

Comment: This is not an ergodic chain. Costal cities are absorbing states. Starting in Scranton, abs in NY is more likely than abs in Seattle, as can be seen by looking at a high power of the transition matrix (say $\mathbf{P}^{64}).$ Scranton, Chicago, and Philadelphia are intercommunicating transient states. Methods using matrix algebra can be used to find mean times in various transient states before abs. Simulation maybe also helpful. // Good question. _Please don't let it get closed:_ Please review methods you.ve used successfully. Say where you're stuck. Focus only on parts where you need help.

Comment: . Also can you give something for this part also?


Jim decides that New York is not in his future. Accordingly, when he is Scranton, he
remains there for another year with probability 1/2, and otherwise he has an equally
likely chance of moving to any of the other cities. When he is in Chicago, his probability
of moving to Scranton or Philadelphia are in the same proportion as before (does not
necessary imply same probability).



 6. Create the revised transition graph and matrix.
 7. What is the expected number of years until Jim is in Seattle?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it .

Answer (score 0):

Put transition matrix into R. Let 1=Sranton, 2=Chi, 3=Phil, 4=NY, and 5=Seattle.

Raise the transition matrix to a high power:

```
P = (1/8)*matrix(c(4,1,1,1,1,
                   3,3,0,0,2,
                   3,0,1,4,0,
                   0,0,0,8,0,
                   0,0,0,0,8), byrow=T, nrow=5)
P; P2 = P%*%P; P4 = P2%*%P2;  P8 = P4%*%P4; P8
P16 = P8%*%P8; P32 = P16%*%P16;  P64 = P32%*%P32 
round(P64, 4)
      [,1] [,2] [,3]   [,4]   [,5]
 [1,]    0    0    0 0.5288 0.4712
 [2,]    0    0    0 0.3173 0.6827
 [3,]    0    0    0 0.7981 0.2019
 [4,]    0    0    0 1.0000 0.0000
 [5,]    0    0    0 0.0000 1.0000
```

Given a start in Scranton, the probability of settling permanently in Seattle is about 0.4712.

The following matrix manipulations answer some of the
questions you list.

```
Q = P[1:3,1:3]    # matrix of transient states
N = P[1:3,4:5]    # moves from trans to abs
I = diag(3)
M = solve(I - Q)  # inverse
M     # mean steps in each transient state until abs
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 2.692308 0.5384615 0.3846154
[2,] 1.615385 1.9230769 0.2307692
[3,] 1.153846 0.2307692 1.3076923
M %*% N  # probabilities of abs in NY (col 1), Seattle
          [,1]      [,2]  # relabel cols as 4 & 5
[1,] 0.5288462 0.4711538
[2,] 0.3173077 0.6826923
[3,] 0.7980769 0.2019231
```

Some books denote elements of $\mathbf{M}$ by $m_{ij}:$ Given a start in stat $i$ what is the mean number of steps in $j$ until absorption.

Some books denote elements of $\mathbf{MN}$ as $f_{ij},$ given a start in $i$ what is the probability of a visit to (here, absorption in)
state $j$ (with column numbers suitably revised
to match absorbing states).

Given a start in Scranton, the exact probability
of absorption in Seattle is 0.4711538. (Compare $\mathbf{MN}$ with the last two columns of $\mathbf{P}^{64}.)$

```
rowSums(M)
[1] 3.615385 3.769231 2.692308
```

Some books denote these values as $M_i = \sum_{j \in T} m_{ij},$ where $T$ is the set of transient states: given a start in state $i,$ the mean
number of steps to absorption.

Mean number of steps to absorption (somewhere) given starts in
Scranton (our case: 3.615385 steps), Chicago or Philadelphia.

Comment: thank you very much for your support i will study these answers